# .split() and .append information from .txt file as tuples to a new list

Tags: python, list, split, append, tuples

I'm trying to read a .txt file line by line with a while loop, split each line at a comma intersection, call a function to return the "date" side of each line to a list, then append the "task" side to the datetime in the list.

Example line in the .txt file: "tutorial signons,28/02/2014"

The result should look like: (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 28, 0, 0), 'tutorial signons')

My code at the moment is returning this:
['t', 'u', 't', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'a', 'l', ' ', 's', 'i', 'g', 'n', 'o', 'n', 's', ',', '2', '8', '/', '0', '2', '/', '2', '0', '1', '4', '\n']

Datetime Function:

```
def as_datetime(date_string):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, DATE_FORMAT)
    except ValueError:
        # The date string was invalid
        return None
```

load_list function:

```
def load_list(filename):
    new_list = []
    f = open("todo.txt", 'rU')
    while 1:
        line = f.readline()
        line.split(',')
        task = line[1:0]
        datetime = as_datetime(line)
        if not line:
            break
        for datetime in line:
            new_list.append(datetime)
        for task in line:
            new_list.append(task)
        return new_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple things:

- Since your date is always on the right, and you may want commas in the command part, consider using `rsplit` instead of `split`. Using `rsplit(',', 1)` will only split at the last comma.
- Capture the split output to two new variables.
- Looks like `"todo.txt"` should be `filename` the way the function is written.
- Use `with` for files where appropriate.
- I'm not sure the purpose of some of the lower logic. I've written the code below to skip lines with no date or unreadabe date.

The edited version looks like:

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
import datetime
def load_list(filename):
    new_list = []
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        for line in f:
            task, date = line.rsplit(',', 1)
            try:
                # strip removes any extra white space / newlines
                date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.strip(), DATE_FORMAT)
            except ValueError:
                continue # go to next line
            new_list.append((date, task))
    return new_list
```

This returns a list of tuples. Which you could easily iterate through:

```
for date, task in load_list('todo.txt'):
    print 'On ' + date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT) + ', do task: ' + task
```

Finally, I would normally suggest using the `csv` module, since your file looks like a csv file. If `task` will never have commas in it, then the `csv.reader()` functionality can replace `rsplit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, the "with" here looks very useful when opening files. This code worked perfectly and removed the need to call the as_datetime function. The file does only contain commas, so I might try using the csv.reader() to split if that is more stable.

Answer (score 1):

you have to capture line.split(',') in a variable.  split doesn't alter the original variable.

Comment: Should the variable look something like: task = line.split(',') how would I specify which side of the split I want to take the value from? Would I use something like task = line.split((',')[0:1]) ?